# SharePoint 2013 workflow to send a reminder

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-online, workflow, designer-workflow, reminder

I have created a document library (but it could also be a list, not a problem) and in this library I have a column"End date" and a column "Owner" which the user needs to fill in. Now I want that SharePoint sends an email to the owner on the end date to notify that the end date of the document/contract has been reached. It seems pretty easy but somehow I am not able to create a working workflow for this (also not with the help of other posts/the internet. I don't know what I am doing wrong). This is what I have so far:

Details of the workflow:
[image]

[image]

[image]

Details of the list on SharePoint: 
[image]

[image]

Is there anyone who can help me out?

Answer (score 5):

It's quite simple: Use pause until like below (`Replace hardcoded date with currentItem:EndDate`)

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have adjusted the workflow but it is still not working... I have made some screenshots of the list and the workflow with details and added them in my question. Hopefully this will help.

Comment: Please log a statement before sending an email, it's possible that there something wrong with your email sending